# RedirectToAction Redirects to a Different ActionResult than Specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently having an issue with my `RedirectToAction` redirecting to the `Dispose()` method included in a generated controller.  I'm not sure why it's going to this method instead of the one I specified.  What I'm trying to do is add an entry to one of my models (`OwnGame`, which is succeeds at) then I want to redirect to an action result that deletes those entries from a previous model/table (`Cart`) once they've been added to the Model/DB Table I mentioned.  Below is the first action result which adds then redirects.

```
//GET: OwnGame/Create
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Member")]
public ActionResult Create(string userEmail)
{
    List<int> GameIDs = new List<int>();
    GameIDs = (List<int>)TempData["CheckoutGameIDs"];
    ViewBag.Email = userEmail;

    for (int i = 0; i < GameIDs.Count; i++)
    {
        ViewBag.GameID = GameIDs[i];
        OwnGame ownedGames = new OwnGame();
        ownedGames.Email = userEmail;
        ownedGames.GameID = GameIDs[i];

        db.OwnGames.Add(ownedGames);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("EmptyCart");
}
```

And if it's relevant I've included the method I wanted to redirect to but it's failing.

```
public ActionResult EmptyCart(string userEmail)
{
    var cartItems = db.Carts.Where(o => o.Email.Contains(userEmail));
    foreach (Cart singleItem in cartItems)
    {
        Cart cartSingleItem = db.Carts.Find(singleItem.CartID);
        db.Carts.Remove(cartSingleItem);               
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { userEmail = userEmail });
}
```

Also I haven't done anything to the `Dispose()` method, it's standard. All of this is supposed to be taking place in the same controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `EmptyCart` has a parameter and you have to specify it's value when you call it from `RedirectToAction`:

```
return RedirectToAction("EmptyCart", new { userEmail = "" });
```

Or as an alternative, you can make that parameter [optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments):

```
public ActionResult EmptyCart(string userEmail = "")
{
    var cartItems = db.Carts.Where(o => o.Email.Contains(userEmail));
    ....
    ....
}
```